# Content Search WebPart: query Date and Time field

Tags: date-time, query, content-search-web-part

I have calendar list,
Now trying to query items which are greater than Today.

so first I have created new managed property with name **EventDate** and mapped the crawled property **ows_EventDate** with type Date and Time
[image] when I used that property in content Search web part query text,
it shows the following error:
"**We didn't understand your search terms. Make sure you're using the proper**"

[image]

Comment: See if this helps - https://spvee.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/content-search-web-part-and-event-dates-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 0):

This issue mostly occcurs when managed property you created is of type text and not datetime.

You can’t use Today when you are mapped to a text field.

So you need to check the datatype of managed property and change to DateTime if its text.

Comment: Amit my Managed property{EventDate} type is Date and Time. please check screen shots.

Comment: After mapping with the managed property did you started full crawl

Comment: Yes. I started full crawl.

Answer (score 0):

Map to refinabledate00 and use that

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/74793)

Comment: It is the answer to their question.  Map the crawlable property to refinabledate00 and use refinabledate00 in the content search wp.  That is what will solve their problem.  If they replace that in the query they have above that will solve their problem.